# Iterating over pandas group is extremely slow and apply function not working properly

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am using `pandas` for generating custom reports for our clients. The flow for generating the reports is as follows:

1. Get data from API
2. Parse through the `pandas` function, perform some business logic, and send the generated report through `email`.

Business Logic:
We have to find the `first-in` & `last-out` time of all people in the data.

## Code:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(report_data)
df["Code"] = df["[People]Employee Code"]
df["Checkin At Date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Checkin At Date"])
df["Checkin At Time"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Checkin At Time"])
grouped_data = df.groupby(["Mobile Number", "Checkin At Date"])
final_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=df.columns)
for key, temp_df in grouped_data:
    try:
        num_of_rows = len(temp_df.index)
        temp_df.sort_values(
            by=["Checkin At Time"], inplace=True, ascending=True
        )
        first_checkin_time = temp_df.loc[
            temp_df.index[0], "Checkin At Time"
        ]
        last_checkin_time = temp_df.loc[
            temp_df.index[-1], "Checkin At Time"
        ]
        temp_df['FIRST_BODY_TEMP'] = temp_df.loc[
            temp_df.index[0], "Body Temp"
        ]
        temp_df['LAST_BODY_TEMP'] = temp_df.loc[
            temp_df.index[-1], "Body Temp"
        ]
        if num_of_rows <= 1:
            temp_df.loc['TOTAL_TIME'] = 0
            temp_df.loc['LAST_OUT_TIME'] = None
        else:
            temp_df['TOTAL_TIME'] = last_checkin_time - first_checkin_time
            temp_df['LAST_OUT_TIME'] = temp_df.loc[
                    temp_df.index[-1], "Checkin At Time"]

            temp_df["TOTAL_TIME"] = pd.to_timedelta(
                temp_df["TOTAL_TIME"], unit="s"
            )
            temp_df["TOTAL_TIME"] = temp_df["TOTAL_TIME"].apply(
                lambda x: strfdelta(x, "{hours} Hrs {minutes} Min")
            )
            temp_df["LAST_OUT_TIME"] = temp_df["LAST_OUT_TIME"].dt.time
        # Fetching the first row of the grouped data and appending to df
        final_df = final_df.append(temp_df.iloc[0], ignore_index=True)
    except Exception as e:
        logger.exception(e)
        continue
```

For a record size of `800 items` this is taking almost `18-20 seconds`.

## Things I have tried:

```
def calculate_attendance(temp_df):
    num_of_rows = len(temp_df.index)
    temp_df.sort_values(by=['Checkin At Time'], inplace=True,
                    ascending=True)
    first_checkin_time = temp_df.loc[temp_df.index[0], 'Checkin At Time'
        ]
    last_checkin_time = temp_df.loc[temp_df.index[-1], 'Checkin At Time'
                                ]
    temp_df['FIRST_BODY_TEMP'] = temp_df.loc[temp_df.index[0],
        'Body Temp']
    temp_df['LAST_BODY_TEMP'] = temp_df.loc[temp_df.index[-1],
        'Body Temp']
    if num_of_rows <= 1:
       temp_df.loc['TOTAL_TIME'] = 0
       temp_df.loc['LAST_OUT_TIME'] = None
    else:
       temp_df['TOTAL_TIME'] = last_checkin_time - first_checkin_time
       temp_df['LAST_OUT_TIME'] = temp_df.loc[temp_df.index[-1],
            'Checkin At Time']

       temp_df['TOTAL_TIME'] = pd.to_timedelta(temp_df['TOTAL_TIME'],
            unit='s')
       temp_df['TOTAL_TIME'] = temp_df['TOTAL_TIME'].apply(lambda x: \
            strfdelta(x, '{hours} Hrs {minutes} Min'))
       temp_df['LAST_OUT_TIME'] = temp_df['LAST_OUT_TIME'].dt.time
       return temp_df.iloc[0]

final_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=df.columns)
final_df = final_df.groupby(["Mobile Number", "Checkin At Date"]).apply(calculate_attendance)
```

## Issue in this step is:

The same group is getting repeated and the `final_df` is of the same rows.

Comment: You don't need to iterate through the groups. You can use the `first()` and `last()` function on the group by object

Comment: @GhandiFloss but there are multiple groups hence `first()` & `last()` will not return relevant data

Comment: it will calculate it for each group, or you could use max() , min ()